Using C/C++ enumeration from .h in Rust
The Cargo project requires using an enumeration from a large C header file. There are at least 1000 different variants of this enumeration.
Here is an example of what the header looks like:
#ifndef MY_ENUMS_H
#define MY_ENUMS_H

enum Status {
   OK = 0,
   OUR_BASE = OK,
   CONNECTION_ERROR = OUR_BASE + 1,
   OPEN_FAILED = OUR_BASE + 2,
   ...
};

#endif // MY_ENUMS_H

I'd like to re-use these in Rust. Is there a way to do this? I've looked into bindgen, but it looks like it compiles, whereas this is header only.

I'd make a parser with nom and friends, and transform into rust enums, maybe with a macro.

Do you need to interop with this enum through FFI? Or do you simply want a similar definition in Rust?

Literally just need it for a similar definition in Rust. The legacy C code is still regularly updated, and being able to pull it in automatically and have the newer variants is a plus.

What's the problem with bindgen? I just tried it with the code you posted and it worked fine.

I think I've figured out how to do it with bindgen. Didn't look straightforward to me when I started looking into it.

You don't need to compile the external library to use bindgen. As long as you have the .h file and then tell your crate to link to the library in your build.rs file you should be good

I ended up using bindgen to accomplish this.
build.rs file:
fn main() {
    let bindings = bindgen::builder().header("./src/include/enum.h").generate().expect("Unable to generate bindings");
    bindings.write_to_file("./src/enum.rs").expect("Couldn't write bindings");
}

src/main.rs file example:
   include!("enum.rs");
   fn main() {
      let status: Status = Status_CONNECTION_ERROR;
   }


As an aside, you can also make the enumerations more like Rust enums, if you add a .default_enum_style(bindgen::EnumVariation::Rust {...}) to the builder. This will prevent the output from looking like Status_CONNECTION_ERROR and more like Status::CONNECTION_ERROR.

Btw, you can use mod enum.rs instead of include!("enum.rs").
